# Sending ping pong messages to check if client is connected to the server ?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am using Websockets,Do I need to send ping pong messages separately upon connecting to the socket to check if the client is alive or Websockets has its inbuilt mechanism to check if the client is connected to it.

Comment: https://github.com/websockets/ws#how-to-detect-and-close-broken-connections

Answer (score 0):

there is a "disconnect" event if you are using "socket.io" package which triggers when the client disconnects the server... so you do not need to check periodically to find put whether the client is on-line or off-line.

check the code below (if you are using socket.io):

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) { //on connect event
   //handling other events ...

   socket.on('disconnect', function() { //on disconnect event
      console.log('Got disconnect!');
   });
});
```

and if you are using web-sockets visit the link @robertklep suggested

hope it helps you ...